# how to change function definition captured in closure

Tags: javascript, closures

This is another Javascript closure question. I run the following code as soon as the document loads:

```
 var handlers = (function () {

    var clickHandler = function() { alert ('click!'); }
    return {
        clickHandler : clickHandler
    }
}());

$('#element').addEventListener('click', handlers.clickHandler);
```

Then at some later point I want to replace the functionality of the handler and thus do something like:

```
handlers.clickHandler = function() { alert ('changed handler!'); }
```

From my understand of Javascript closures the event listener should keep a reference of the clickHandler function, and thus the functionality should change accordingly. Yet, this is not what happens. The event listener triggers the initial function. I have managed to achieve the result I want using `eval` but this feels like a hack. Is there a legitimate way to do what I want?

Comment: I think you want to detatch the event `$('#element').unbind( "click" );` http://api.jquery.com/unbind/ and then after that add the new Event Handler `$('#element').addEventListener('click',  function() { alert ('changed handler!'); });`

Comment: Hello Nick, thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this is not possible in my case (long story). This is why I am searching a solution in the lines of what I have described. Again, thank you.

Comment: understand that when you do `var g = function(){ console.log('hello world')}; h = g; g= function(){ console.log('dead')}; h();` we get as output 'hello world' because the original function still exists you are just changing what g is pointing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#element').on('click', /*the solution: */ () => handlers.clickHandler());
```

You need to resolve the identifier on execution of the handler, not on registration. That can be done by wrapping the call into a function, like i did above ( with an arrow function).

Comment: Hello Jonas, thank you for your suggestion. I will test it tomorrow and mark it as correct if it works. Could you add a couple of words why this solves my problem? What does this notation mean? Again, many thanks.